# I need to disable user interaction with either the keyboard or the entire app

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` that brings up the keyboard and right now, once you tap "Go", you can still edit the text field while things are loading (more importantly, you're interacting with the keyboard and can still press the return key again, which creates a bunch of problems).

I've tried `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]`, but you can still interact with the keyboard. I don't want to hide the keyboard while it loads because if the entry is invalid, the user will need to use the keyboard again. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're handling this the wrong way. What I would do is this:

Once the user hits "Go" and the loading starts, hide the keyboard and disable user interaction on the textfield.

If there is an invalid entry, enable the textfield again and bring up the keyboard.

As far as I know, if the keyboard is in view, it cannot be disabled (And for good reason, thats poor UI design. )

Comment: You're making me rethink this. However, if the entry is correct, the keyboard disappears completely at the same time the next view displays completely. If the entry is invalid, the user has to wait till the keyboard slides up to fix the problem (inefficient). This happens to be the same time that the alert box fades away completely which happens to make it convenient, but if it were a static keyboard, would your UI design philosophy still apply? It would still need to be disabled, right?

Comment: Its simple, if the keyboard is on screen, the its inviting the user to enter text. If the user can't interact with they keyboard it will actually seem pointless and frustrating. The keyboard only takes half a second to come up on screen, if that. So its not a long wait time. Also, you make the textfield the firstResponder when the keyboard comes back into view, making it easy and convenient for the user to just start typing and hitting "Go" to retry. That works much better than having a keyboard you can't use on screen...

Comment: I tried your method and it looks good. Just a side note, the popular and successful app "Songza" disagrees with your UI design philosophy, however, they weren't able to disable the keyboard either and you can press Go multiple times to make it glitch out. If the keyboard was disabled though, their design does look pretty good and streamlined. Thanks for your input.

Comment: The fact that you can press Go and make it glitch out tells me their design is poor. Glad you came right.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this,assume goClicked method is fire method when you clicked on "GO"

```
- (void)goClicked
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
   [yourTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

   //loading things code
   //when loading completes or loading fails
   [yourTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```